# Plotting a segmentation plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, seaborn

I have a data frame

```
    Rfm  Count    %
0   111  88824  57.13
1   112  5462   3.51
2   121  32209  20.72
3   122  15155  9.75
4   211  5002   3.22
5   212  1002   0.64
6   221  3054   1.96
7   222  4778   3.07
```

How can I plot a graph like this?

Background - The numbers are the RFM scores. 
R is Repeat (number of days since customer ordered)
F is frequency (number of jobs from customers)
M is monetary (how much customer is paying)

The `R,F` and `M` scores are either `1 (bad)` or `2 (good)`.

I would like to segment them into 4 `Quadrants`.

I would also like the size of the `blob` to be proportional to the percentage.

I.e. `blob 111 (57%)` will be much larger than `blob 212 (0.64%)`.

I really want to get better at data visualization, please help a beginner out. I'm familiar with `seaborn` and `matplotlib`.

Ps: Is it possible to add a third dimension to the plot? 3rd Dim would be the frequency.

Edit: The second image is a simple static way of achieveing my goal. Any input for doing it with matplotlib or seaborn? For a more interesting illustration.

[image]

[Second Image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuzEM.jpg)

Comment: Love the hand-drawn graph, but I'm really not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. How are x & y values determined? Where are these quadrants coming from? Is `Count` used for anything?

Comment: Hi busybear, the RFM values are discrete categories. So in a sense it’s categorical data. The ‘x’ is an increase in the ‘R’ value- ‘1 or 2’. For example, ‘122’ is a ‘R’ score of ‘1’, ‘F’ score of ‘2’ and ‘M’ score of ‘2’. The quadrants are my idea of grouping them. ‘Count’ was used to find out how many rows of data fell into each RFM category. My original data frame had around 27k rows.